# How to select not first tr and not last td

Tags: css, css-selectors

```css
#MyTable tr+tr:hover {
  background: #dfdfdf;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I managed to hover row 2 and 3 but while hover on 2 and 3, how can I skip the td (X). Preferable not using jQuery selector.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use the [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/%3anot), [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/%3afirst-child) and [:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/%3alast-child).

```
#myTable tr:not(:first-child):hover td:not(:last-child) {
      background: #dfdfdf;
}
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/5PfGR/).

Comment: `:not` doesn't work until IE 9 sadly. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html, then again neither do `:last-child` nor `:first-child`...

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to not apply something to the first and last children, you can use the `:first-child` and `:last-child` selectors to override the styles.

```
#MyTable tr, tr:hover { 
    background: #dfdfdf;
}

#MyTable tr:first-child, tr:last-child {
    background: #000;
}
```

This won't work in IE until [IE 9 though](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

[Unless you shim in some support](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills).

Answer (score 2):

I found this SO link because I did not want my header row to highlight when I hovered over it.  The solution I came up with was to use `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags and apply css to the rows within `<tbody>`.

```
<style>
    .report tbody tr:hover {
        background-color: khaki;
    }
</style>

<table class="report">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Value</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Total</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

`:not(:first-child)` and `:not(:last-child)` should do the trick, it seems those are supported by all latest browser.
If you need IE<9 support you can add classes, or replace `td`'s with `th`'s